# Unity IAspect with items of type Aspect

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-ecs

I am Using Unity Dots with Entities 1.0.8.

This are my aspect definitions:

```
public readonly partial struct StandardAspect : IAspect
{
    public readonly Entity Entity;
    public readonly RefRO<StandardData> StandardData;
}
```

```
public readonly partial struct ExtendedAspect : IAspect
{
    public readonly StandardAspect StandardAspect;
    public readonly RefRO<ExtendedData> ExtendedData;
}
```

My entity has the ComponentData `StandardData` and `ExtendedData`.

The Unity Editor shows me that the entity fits the aspects `StandardAspect` and `ExtendedAspect`.

On runtime I remove the `StandardData`-Component from the entity so that Unity detects that the entity doesn't fit the `StandardAspect` anymore.

What seems odd to me is:
According to Unity the Entity still fits the aspect `ExtendedAspect`.

Did I do something wrong?

Is this a bug?

Is there another way to "extend" or "nest aspects?

Comment: `IAspect`s were supposed to simplify things and yet they raise more questions and increase complexity. Let me advise against using them at all - humble queries are completely fine and you can do whatever you need just fine without all that `IAspect` drama.